# Itamaeでcronジョブを設定する方法

Tags: itamae, provisioning, cron

Itamaeで`cron`の設定を行いたかったのですが、`cron`リソースがなくどのようにするのが推奨なのかドキュメントもなかったのでこちらの[Twitterのつぶやき](https://twitter.com/ryot_a_rai/status/505244030825807872)を見て`/etc/cron.d/my_task`という名前で下記のジョブを設定したのですが動いていません。

```
15 * * * * echo hoge > /var/log/hogehoge.txt
```

`/etc/cron.d`にファイルを置くだけでは`crond`で自動的に読み込まれないのでしょうか？

また、[こちらのサイト](http://yuumi3.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/08/17/152016)のように`cron`のためのリソースを自分で定義するのが良いのでしょうか？

試したことを書くと質問が少し散漫になってしまいましたが、知りたいことは「Itamaeで`cron`の設定をするにはどうするか？」になります。

Answer (score 1):

ちょっとよくないやり方かもしれませんが、私はcronの実体ファイルを書き換えています。

```
template "root cron set" do
    path   "/var/spool/cron/root"
    source "templates/var/spool/cron/root.erb"
    owner "root"
    group "root"
    mode   "644"
end
```

Comment: 回答ありがうございます。ただ複数のレシピからcronを呼び出したいので`/var/spool/cron/root`の書き換えだと分割できなくて困るんですよね…。

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/cron.d/` 以下はシステムcronの設定になるので、実行ユーザの記載が必要です。crontabのmanで以下の部分に書かれている内容です。

> Each  line  has  five time and date fields, followed by a user name if
>   this is the system crontab file, followed by a command.

crontabは`echo`というユーザを探してしまっているんですね。今回の設定であれば(rootで実行したい場合)`/etc/cron.d/my_task`を以下のように書けば実行されると思いますよ。

```
15 * * * * root echo hoge > /var/log/hogehoge.txt
```